# In the Kile build tool configuration, which token expands to the live preview file?

Tags: kile

In the Kile Latex editor, I can configure different viewers via:

```
Settings -> Configure Kile... -> Tools -> Build
```

Now, I want to configure Evince as a viewer to open the live preview, to do this, I need to pass the file name to evince via the `Options` field.

Kile provides the special token `%target` or `file:%dir_target/%target` which resolved to the compiled PDF file.

What token do I need to use to open the compiled live preview file under `/tmp/kile-livepreview<something>/<target>.pdf`?

I use Kile 2.9.91.